# How to Update Sphinx data through PHP

Tags: php, rotation, sphinx

I am updating Sphinx data from command prompt with the following command

```
indexer --all --rotate
```

It'll updates the new records, is there any way to update Sphinx data using `Sphinxql.php` or `sphinxai.php`

Answer (score 0):

No. disk indexes are created by the `indexer` program. Its only possible to run it on the command line. Its not possible to start it off by one of the querying methods.

Its most usual to run `indexer` via crontab, so its automatic.

---

There are Real-Time (RT) indexes, which ***instead*** of using `indexer`, you add/remove documents **individually** via SphinxQL commands. So rather than adding everything via a batch process, you add them one by one (usually at the same time as adding them to the database)

- hence the name Real-Time, as can add the document to the database and be able to search it in real-time, rather than the slight delay between adding the document, and running `indexer`.